# a global function for url query

Tags: php

I have written a function:

```
function url_query(){
  if (is_numeric($_GET['cmd'])) {
    $get = $_GET['cmd'];
  }
  return $get;
}
```

but I want that this function be global. This function works only for eg.

```
index.php?cmd=...
```

Can I revise this function to use for index.php?page=... and index.php?catID=... etc?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want the parameters of cmd, page and catID returned?

Comment: have you ever heard about function arguments? joking apart, it is what you needed: an argument to your function; unless you're saying something different, like "automatically" checks for evry $_GET and return those that are numeric only... easy as foreach-ing on $_GET and building a new array selecting through is_numeric (you can use filter in this case: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php )

Comment: @Adam; Yes.. @shin, Yes, I have heard about arguments. I have tried this: function url_query($cmd){ if (is_numeric($_GET['$cmd'])) { $cmd = $_GET['$cmd']; } return $cmd; } Thansk for joking, thanks for help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function url_query($param){
  $get = null;
  if (isset($_GET[$param]) && is_numeric($_GET[$param])) {
    $get = $_GET[$param];
  }
  return $get;
}
```

I've ensured that the return value is null if the parameter is not numeric, so that client code has to explicitly check for that case.

Comment: Umm, if you return a variable that never gets defined, it is already NULL, you don't have to define it as NULL...

Comment: I have tried :
function url_query($cmd){
    if (is_numeric($_GET['$cmd'])) {
        $cmd = $_GET['$cmd'];
        
    }
    return $cmd;
}
And this was not worked. I think that the problem because double qouetes.
Thanks alot.

Comment: Well, actually I don't know what the return value would be. But it definitely would raise an E_NOTICE error. Plus, it would rely on a language "hack" to get the work done, whereas I prefer code to be obvious.

Comment: @phpExe You added some extra apostrophes
It's $_GET[$cmd], not $_GET['$cmd'].

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
function url_query($queryParam){ 
   if (is_numeric($_GET[$queryParam])) {
     $get = $_GET[$queryParam];
  }
 return $get;

}
```

Or with an array:

```
function url_query($queryParams){ 

 $get = array();

 foreach($queryParams as $queryParam){ 

    if (is_numeric($_GET[$queryParam])) {
     $get[] = $_GET[$queryParam];
    }
  }
 return $get;
}
```

Possible calls:

```
$value = url_query('cmd');

$values = url_query(array('cmd','catID'));
```

Comment: Don’t forget to use `isset` or `array_key_exists`!